# How to mix 100% height with a minimum height

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is simple, the solution though doesn't seem particularly obvious.

I have a Flash site. Currently the Flash object takes up the whole browser and is set to `width/height = 100%`. This is fine until someone shrinks their browser.

Is there a way to set something like this this.

```
height = (browser_height < y) ? y : 100%;
width = (browser_width < x) ? x : 100%;
```

x and y being the minimum dimension the site needs to display properly.

Is there a CSS way to do this? If not could some tell me how to keep track of the browsers viewable area across all browsers?

Comment: Definitely not CSS - although there is a `min-height` and `min-width` property, those are not meant for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `x` and `y` are known, you can do it by setting [min-height](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-height.asp) and [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-width.asp) on the element that contains your flash object:

```
<body>
    <div id="flastObj">
        flash object code here
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* 100% height only works if the element's direct parent (body in 
   this example) also has a height specified */
html, body, #flashObj {
    height: 100%;
}

#flashObj {
    min-height: 900px; /* y value */
    min-width: 900px;  /* x value */
}
```

As for keeping track of viewable area cross-browser, I would recommend using a Javascript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  It makes it very easy to capture the window resize event and then act on it:

```
// constant width
var x = 900;

// Bind a handler to the window's load and resize events
$(window).bind('load resize', function(){
    // $(this) is a jQuery object that represent the element (our window) 
    // that we've got the event handlers bound to.
    var newWidth = $(this).width();
    var newHeight = $(this).height();

    // Now we can act on our #flashObj element
    var flashObj = $('#flashObj');
    if(newWidth < x){
        flashObj.css({width: x});
    } 
});
```